# Displaying data from a mysql database from start date to end date using php where user provides the start and end date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

hi
 how to Display data from a mysql database from start date to end date using php codeigniter
 where user provides the start and end date through view page..
The start and end date are been fetched from the view page.... so it should be able to fetch the values from the start date till the end date from the mysql database.. ....

i get this output... it displays the current date

> **2009-11-01 00:00:00 SELECT * FROM border WHERE dateordered='2009-11-01 00:00:00'2011-05-04No Records Found2010-11-01 00:00:00** 
>   but i gave the start date as 04-05-2011 and end date 05-05-2011

Comment: that makes no sense.. at all. use '>' and '<' operators.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY start_date ASC';
$q = $this->db->query($sql);

$results = ($q ? $q->result() : FALSE);
```

there you go....

Answer (score 1):

`$this->db->where("date BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '2011-05-11'");`

I've never used CodeIgnitet, but I believe they use this kind of method to run the query.

Oh, I might have misunderstood you, if this is not what your looking for, see the answer of the other guy, just use an `ORDER BY datefield` and use `ASC` from oldest to newest or `DESC` for newest to oldest.

Comment: Don't think OP has quite explained it as clearly as possible - quite possibly both of us are right. I see this as a PHP question, not a MySQL question - but OP might need to ask a MySQL question too by the looks of it....

Comment: ah well, let's hear what he's got to say, meanwhile I'll +1 your post ;-)

Comment: The start and end date are been fetched from the view page.... so it should be able to fetch the values from the start date till the end date from the mysql database.. ....

Comment: the output you get seems strange (not taking any dates). I guess you're missing something in your PHP that checks up if there's a date given and adds it to the query?